# Is this an official game or a mod of the FM-Towns Japanese release?

Tags: game-identification, zak-mckracken

Many years ago a game called Zak McKracken and the Alien Mindbenders was released on the PC.  Here is a screenshot of the PC version of the game:

[image: pc-version]

A 256 colour version was released on the FM Towns machine for the Japanese market:

[image: fm-japan]

As well as better graphics, the game also had all the characters with anime style eyes:

[image: anime]

However, I have come across screenshots and videos of an English version of the FM Towns game (without the anime eyes).  For example:

[image: fm-english]

I cannot work out if the English version is an unofficial modded version or a legitimate release.

Does anyone know if the 256 colour, English, non-anime version was a "real" release of the game?

**RE: GOG release**

I can see that an English 256 colour was released by GOG in Mar 2015:

[GOG Release News](https://www.gog.com/news/release_zak_mckracken_and_the_alien_mindbenders)

But there are earlier sources such as this 2008 video on youtube:

Comment: Seems like the [Gog release](https://www.gog.com/game/zak_mckracken_and_the_alien_mindbenders), searching google with the image lead me to wiki which mentioned the gog's release.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau - I updated info at the bottom of the question.  In short, there are sources of the English 256 colour version several years before the GOG release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that both versions of the game are part of the same FM Towns release.  When you launch the game you are given a choice of whether to play in English or Japanese.

[image: FM Towns Language Menu]

Note that the third option is a collection of demos (common at the time for LucasArts releases).

I assume that the GOG release is based on the English language version of this FM Towns release.